# Ways to say "more"

Tags: word-choice, grammar

I know a few ways to say "more" or "in addition", and I'm wondering which to use when translating this sentence. I came across the following English sentence and its Chinese translation on [tatoeba.org](http://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/show/890676).

> May I ask you some more questions?
>
> 我可以問你一些問題嗎？

To me, it looks like the Chinese version has slightly changed the meaning to "May I ask you some questions?" Is that right, or is the "more" somehow implied?

If I wanted to propose an alternate translation that clearly talks about "more questions", would any of these work?

- 我可以再问你一些问题嗎？
- 我可以問你更多問題嗎？
- 我可以問你一些更多問題嗎？

Are there better ways to translate this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `May I ask you some more questions?`

> 我可以再问你一些问题吗？

This is the way we speak.

or `我可以再问你几个问题吗？`

Here 几个 doesn't mean "how many"; while it means "several". And 再 means "again". So "several again" refers to "some more".

or `可以再问你几个问题吗？`

because the subject of a sentence in Chinese is not always necessary -- saying like this infers that "it's me who want to ask more questions".

or `可以再问几个问题吗？`

if the conversation happens only between two people ("you" and "I").

> 我可以問你更多問題嗎？

This is not a wrong sentence, but we'd rather not use it.

> 我可以問你一些更多問題嗎？

一些 and 更多 should not be used together directly like this. This is like a sentence translated word by word with a translation software.

Comment: I suspected that 一些 and 更多 didn't sound right together. Thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: Note that 再 can also mean 'again'. To say 'I want to ask you this question again', it can be differentiated by saying 我想再問一次這個問題 or 我想再問你一次. (Any native speakers care to comment?)

Comment: @Bathrobe It's OK. Note that 我想再問一次這個問題 or 我想再問你一次 infers that you are asking for the “same question” again.

Answer (score 2):

*** NON NATIVE-SPEAKER DISCLAIMER ***

How about something using 另外?

Like:

> *我还有一些另外的问题。
>
> 我还有另外一些问题。

EDIT: Corrected following comment :D

Comment: 另外 is also OK. However, I would prefer saying 我还有另外一些问题。 另外 should be used before 一些; also, I think 另外 should be an adverb rather than an adjective.

Comment: @coolcfan okay cool.. I starred my (incorrect) version and added a correct one

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to say 我还有几个问题想问你.

Comment: And also, to say it like a native speaker, "我还有几个问题".